# Fetching facebook data in c# using Parse

Tags: c#, facebook, windows-phone-8, parse-platform

I'm currently developing an app for windows phone 8.0 that needs to fetch Facebook data(username) and display and then save it in a Parse Cloud server. I'm using *Parse-Single sign on mechanism*.The app authenticates through Facebook, connects successfully to Parse-server **but I cannot fetch data** I have tried graph API, but it doesn't seem to work...
Any help appreciated :)

Comment: Please be more specific about what exactly have you tried and how exactly did it not work.

Comment: it would be appreciated if you can show some existing code...!